react native flatlist: "Encountered two children with the same key..." when there is an empty object and another object with an id property
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, Text } from "react-native";

export default function ChatsList() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20, paddingTop: 50 }}
      // data={[0]}
      data={[{ id: 999 }, {}, { id: 1 }]}
      renderItem={({ index }) => (
        // <Text key={index}>{`bamboozled ${index}\n`}</Text>
        <Text key={index}>{`placeholder ${index}\n`}</Text>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(_item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  );
}

I am dumbfounded. Here I have a list of 3 objects. The object at index 1 is empty. If there is another object after that with an id property of value 1, I get a warning,

Encountered two children with the same key, 1...
... even though there is no duplicate.

If I comment that data out and switch to the data that's just a list with 1 entry, the warning disappears but the item at index 1 from the previous data remains, even preserving the previous renderItem logic (as demonstrated in the video).
If I repeatedly do this, I keep getting "ghost" entries that accumulates at the top of the FlatList.
Using a keyExtractor as shown prevents this, and toggling it on and off using comments produces the same duplication behaviour as described previously.
What the hell is going on? Is this intended behaviour? A glitch? Should I report it?


Definitely report it.

This is expected behaviour. In Flatlist you should provide a keyExtractor to give every item in the list a unique key. This is how react-native identify items. You should always give keyExtractor prop to Flatlist. This is a good practice for both performance and correctly updating the views inside Flatlist.
Also if you are mapping an array inside a ScrollView or any other View you should give a unique key prop to each item inside that mapping like in your example. Here is an example.


  const data = [{id: 999}, {}, {id: 1}];

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{padding: 20, paddingTop: 50}}>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <Text key={index}>{`placeholder ${index}\n`}</Text>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );



To summerize inside the Flatlist give keyExtractor inside the mapping of an array give key prop and make sure it is unique.

why does providing a unique key prop to each item inside the FlatList not work?
